# Doxygen exclude path in caller graph?

Tags: c, doxygen, graphviz

Given the example, is there a way to tell doxygen to exclude graph paths crossing the function B1()?

```
static void A1(unsigned char select);
static void B1(int select);
static void C1();
static void D1();
static void E1();

static void
A1(unsigned char select)
{
    switch()
    {
    case 'C': C1();
    case 'D': D1();
    case 'E': E1();
    }
}

B1(int select)
{
    A1((unsigned char)select);
}

static void
C1(void)
{

}

static void
D1(void)
{
    int callE = 69;
    B1(callE);
}

static void
E1(void)
{

}

static void
F1(void)
{
    A1('C');
}
```

[image]

Any similar issue I have seen online suggest either it can’t be done or try excluding the function from the document. I tried excluding D1() from the documentation and  Doxygen didn’t document the function but still included it in graphs and reference lists (\cond and \endcond used).

Edit: 'desired graph'

[image]

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "to exclude graph paths crossing the function B1()"? Maybe you can create a picture for it? Did you have a look at MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH or EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS?

Comment: @albert I have played with 'MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH', it effects paths in the graph I do want to include. I have not got 'EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS' to work for me yet but I am looking at it.

Comment: @albert I am building a graph to show the desired result now.

Comment: EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS did the trick. It would be nice if there was a way to just edit the graph and still document the function. :(